# Open Cypress browser when running from Jenkins

Tags: javascript, jenkins, automation, cypress

I created in Jenkins a freestyle project in which I wanted to run Cypress.

In the command line I used this command line:

```
npx cypress run --browser chrome --headed  --spec  "cypress/integration/examples/actions.spec.js" --config pageLoadTimeout=10000
```

The issue that it runs silent mode, there is no browser that is open, and perform test actions.

[image]

What should I do so that the browser appears while executing the test? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CI tools like Jenkins aren't designed to open browser.

That is why Cypress offers two ways to run it:

- For local dev/debug: `cypress open`
- For CI/automatisation : `cypress run`

You are using it the right way.

Interesting things for CI are [screenshots and videos](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/screenshots-and-videos#Screenshots).

Comment: So , if want to run cypress from Jenkins , there is no way to open the browser ?

Comment: Exactly, but whats i your goal ? Maybe [screenshots and videos](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/screenshots-and-videos) options can cover your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, actually when you launch tests based on Cypress on CI (not only Jenkins) - you can't watch the process in debug mode.
Only on the local machine with the `open` parameter.
Also, save the video OR screenshots of running tests from Jenkins - and look after

Answer (score 0):

I used this simple steps and this worked for me ...
I used cypress test for angular application

1. Find out node image comes along with cypress
   -> Eg for node 18 version -  'image 'cypress/base:18.16.0'
   for testing
   run the following commands

   ```
   stage('Run Test') {
       steps {
       sh 'npm start &'

       // Wait for Angular application to start
       sh 'npx wait-on http://localhost:4200'

       // Run Cypress tests
       sh 'NO_COLOR=1 npx cypress run'

       sh 'pkill -f "npm start"'


       }
   }
   ```

Whole pipeline script for Angular Application Build Test(By Cypress) Deploy (dist folder)

Note - Make sure you install all the dependecies of cypress
I changed my few scripts of ng serve , build and test

```
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "./node_modules/.bin/ng serve",
"build": "./node_modules/.bin/ng build",
"watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
"test": "./node_modules/.bin/ng test --watch=false",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"cypress:run": "node_modules/.bin/cypress run",
"cypress:open": "node_modules/.bin/cypress open"
```

}

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
        //image 'node:18-alpine'
         image 'cypress/base:18.16.0'
        args '-u root:root'
        reuseNode true
    }
}

environment {
    GIT_URL = 'https://github.com/nandiniachugatala/app-3.git'
    EMAIL_TO = 'nandiniachugatla@gmail.com'
    EMAIL_FROM = 'nandiniachugatla@gmail.com'
    EMAIL_SUBJECT = 'Notify - Angular project Build Successful'
    EMAIL_BODY = 'Angular project Build Successful done.'
    EMAIL_CC = ''
    EMAIL_BCC = ''
    EMAIL_REPLY_TO = ''
}

stages {
    stage('Node Version') {
        steps {
            sh 'node --version'
        }
    }

    stage('Getting Repo from GitHub') {
        steps {
            git url: env.GIT_URL
        }
    }

    stage('Build Project') {
        steps {
            sh 'rm -rf node_modules'
            sh 'npm cache clean --force'
            sh 'npm install'
        }
    }
    
    stage('Notify Build Success') {
        steps {
            mail to: env.EMAIL_TO, cc: env.EMAIL_CC, bcc: env.EMAIL_BCC,
                 from: env.EMAIL_FROM, replyTo: env.EMAIL_REPLY_TO,
                 subject: env.EMAIL_SUBJECT, body: env.EMAIL_BODY
        }
    }


    stage('Run Test') {
        steps {
        sh 'npm start &'

        // Wait for Angular application to start
        sh 'npx wait-on http://localhost:4200'

        // Run Cypress tests
        sh 'NO_COLOR=1 npx cypress run'

        sh 'pkill -f "npm start"'


        }
    }
    
     stage('Deploy Project') {
        steps {
            sh 'npm run build'
        }
    }


} 
}
```

Hope it will Help : ))